# Do Not interpret as Make variable in Make command

Tags: makefile

I have this code in a Makefile:

```
$(TCLNAME).batch.tcl: $(TCLNAME).tcl
      echo source $::env(TOOLS_DIR)/my.tcl > $@
```

What I want to be printed in `$(TCLNAME)` is:
`source $::env(TOOLS_DIR)/my.tcl`

But I get an error because `$::env(TOOLS_DIR)` is being interpreted as a Make variable and it is expecting `(` after the `$`.

How do I make it to print that line as is and not interpret it as Make variable ?
I tried to use escape character such as `\$::env(TOOLS_DIR)` but that also did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `$` with another `$`, and the parentheses with backslashes:

```
$(TCLNAME).batch.tcl: $(TCLNAME).tcl
    echo source $$::env\(TOOLS_DIR\)/my.tcl > $@
```

Comment: That's not enough: you need to escape the `$` from the shell, too.  I recommend using single quotes around the entire string to be echo'd, rather than backslashes.

Comment: @MadScientist: I don't ordinarily question your posts -- your technical knowledge of Make is superior to mine -- but I don't see the problem. How does my solution fail? Does it depend on the choice of shell? If I can verify the error, I'll delete my Answer.

Comment: In many, maybe even most, shells it will work OK because the character after the unquoted `$` is not a valid character and so most shells will not expand it.  That is, `$foo` is expanded as a shell variable `foo` (which the OP did not want) but for most shells `$:` is not expanded and just passed through (which the OP did want).  However, according to POSIX the behavior of `sh` if the character after an unquoted `$` is not one of the "normal" ones, is unspecified which means the shell could do something else.  Safest is to quote all `$` from the shell to avoid expansion.

Comment: @MadScientist: I have not found a failure case, but I believe that the danger exists. I will delete this Answer. **EDIT:** I am unable to delete an accepted Answer. These comments must suffice.

Comment: You can just edit the question to add the quotes; that's all that's needed.  The answer is fine as-is it just could be a bit more safe.

Answer (score 0):

A more universal escape method, as suggested by MadScientist:

- Replace each `$` with `$$`. The `$` is the only symbol that Make has special treatment for.
- Enclose the whole string in single quotes. Make doesn't care about them, they are for the shell.

  - If you need to *print* single quotes, replace each `'` with `'\''`.

The end result:

```
echo 'source $$::env(TOOLS_DIR)/my.tcl' > $@
```

This way, only `$` needs to be doubled (to prevent Make from interpreting it as a variable). Everything else is handled by the single quotes (which have no special meaning for Make, and are there for the shell).